# SSL, Socket.io, NGINX , Node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I am running a  node js application  and  having problems with NGINX lately,  I could solve all of them somehow  but here is the latest.  When I listen my sockets from

var socket = io.connect('https://www.example.co.uk');

Any one has an idea where this problem comes?
This is my nginx file

```
# Sockets redirect

upstream rest_node_js {
    server  127.0.0.1:8088;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.co.uk;

     ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/private/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/cert.key;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://rest_node_js;
        proxy_redirect off;   
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;



    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.co.uk;
    return 301 https://example.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.co.uk;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.co.uk/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.co.uk;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.co.uk/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you try to Google this error message? try "nginx blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"

Comment: I have been trying that and some other different options, unfortunately  no chance

Comment: The first thing you should look into is: Where does/did this redirect come from. Your request was answered with a redirect from `example.co.uk` to `chicolandcaldicot.co.uk`, which I assume is not desired since the nginx.conf only listenes for `example.co.uk`.
Second: You are using permanent redirects in your nginx.conf, so even if the redirect to above domain has been removed, your clients (e.g. browser) may still have cached them. Always use temporary redirects until you're absolutely sure that you're done testing.

Comment: Please add the CORS-headers config you tried to the question.